# UInt32 array to Double array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uint32

I need to multiply 2 matrices in swift, so in order to use accelerate I need 2 arrays with type double. The issue is, the two arrays that I need to multiply are type UInt32. Is there anyway to convert a UInt32 array to a double array?

```
var UInt32TestArray: [UInt32] = [1,4,2,3]
var Int32TestArray: [Double] = [Double](UInt32) //Doesn't work
```

Comment: Suggest not capitalizing variables names - they look like type names.  And, naming a `[Double]` type as `Int32TestArray` is confusing.  Just style suggestions.  Cheers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use

```
UInt32TestArray.map { Double($0) }
```

to get an array of `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a cast for these types of things. Usually you use a map function for converting an array of one type to another. An answer to a similar question can be found here. [Conversion of entire array from int to double in order to do some aritmetic operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668187/conversion-of-entire-array-from-int-to-double-in-order-to-do-some-aritmetic-oper)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var Int32TestArray = UInt32TestArray.map{UInt32(abs($0))}
```